# Very complex linq

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

I'm having trouble rewriteing a complex sql query as linq.

```
-- gets the SpecificationAttributeOptionIDs that are in the FilteredSpecs list, but don't match
    SELECT * FROM #FilteredSpecs [fs] 
                            WHERE [fs].SpecificationAttributeOptionID NOT IN 
                            ( 
                                -- gets the SpecificationAttributeOptionIDs that match
                                SELECT psam.SpecificationAttributeOptionID 
                                FROM dbo.Nop_Product_SpecificationAttribute_Mapping psam 
                                WHERE psam.AllowFiltering = 1 AND psam.ProductID = 1 
                            )
```

basically what I have, is a list FilteredSpec which is C# is a List of int. I'm trying to get all products that have all the attributeoptions from the FilteredSpec list set.

What I've tried is this (which given my limited knowledge of linq obviously doesn't work):

```
var query = from p in Products
                        where (p.NpProductSpecificationAttributes.Select(a => filters.Contains(a.NpSpecificationAttributeOption.SpecificationAttributeOptionId)).Count() == 0)
                        select p;
```

Can anybody guide me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably the simplest:

```
var query = Products.Where(
    p => FilteredSpec.All(
       fs => p.NpProductSpecificationAttributes.Any(
          a => a.NpSpecificationAttributeOption.AllowFiltering &&
               a.NpSpecificationAttributeOption.SpecificationAttributeOptionId == fs)));
```

It is possible that LINQ to Entities won't know how to translate this if FilteredSpec is actually a List object. If that's the case, let me know and we'll see if we can come up with some other solution.

Comment: Wow. thanks. You are a linq genius :)) Both of them work, and think the second one is a bit faster with cleaner sql. I haven't figured out though how to test if the NpProductSpecificationAttribute has the AllowFiltering property set to true

Comment: I managed to do test for that attribute in the end. Much easier then I though. Thanks for the solution. You are the best!

Comment: @Tudor Carean: I edited the second answer to check the AllowFiltering property, and got rid of the first answer (which would have been more complicated).

Answer (score 4):

First off, never use Count() unless you really need to know exactly how many elements there are.  Using Count() to test for an empty set may require walking through the entire dataset.  This is critical for performance when your dataset size is bigger than a handful of items.  Use ! .Any() instead of .Count() == 0, .Any() instead of .Count() > 0.

Next, your NOT IN test in the original SQL sounds like a set difference operation.  In LINQ, that is represented by .Except()   A.Except(B) returns all the elements of A that are not found in B.

I'm a little confused by your problem description.  In text you say you want to find all the products that have all the attributeoptions found in the FilterSpec list.  But in both of your code samples, you're using NOT IN or testing for Contains returning an empty result, which seems to be running in the opposite direction of your text description.

If you are trying to find all the products that have all the attributeoptions found in the FilterSpec list, then you are looking for set equivalence.

If the items in your attributeoptions and your filterspec list are always listed in a particular order, then you could use Linq's .SequenceEqual() function.  I'll assume your attributeoptions are not ordered, so .SequenceEqual() isn't the right solution.

To test two sets of values A and B for equivalence independent of order, you can test for A.Except(B) is empty and B.Except(A) is empty.  Use ! .Any() to test for empty.  The first one says that everything in A can be found in B, and the second one says everything in B can be found in A.  What else is there?  Nothing, so the two sets must contain exactly the same elements.

Try something like this (not tested):

```
var query = from p in Products
            where !p.NpProductSpecificationAttributes.Except(filters).Any() &&
                  !filters.Except(p.NpProductSpecificationAttributes).Any()
            select p;
```

You can probably get better performance by using a HashSet, if only to reduce the number of times hashsets must be created internally by the expression above.  The code below assumes that there are no duplicate items in the filters list nor in the product attributes.  If your SpecificationAttributeOptionId is not a primitive type (string, int) you may need to specify an equality comparer as well.

```
    var filterset = new HashSet<filteritemtype>(filters);
    var query = from p in Products
                where filterset.SetEquals(new HashSet<itemtype>(p.NpProductSpecificationAttributes))
                select p;
```